# Unable to unzip the WAR file inside Tomcat 6 server

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I uploaded the WAR file to the Tomcat 6 server in `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps`. Usually Tomcat 6 server unzips the WAR file. I alreay uploaded 2 WAR files which automatically unzipped by Tomcat 6 server. When I uploaded the 3rd WAR file it didn't unzip automatically. I have the web app connected to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisely Tomcat does not simply *unzip* the WAR. It makes various operations needed to *deploy* the webapp starting from the WAR.

There must be some problem inside the WAR. E.g. a corrupted JAR in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Try

- copying another time the WAR in `webapps` folder (overwriting the previous copy)
- stopping and restarting Tomcat